# Docusign view only document is not going to the correct recipients

Tags: docusignapi

I have one document that I am sending to 3 people to view only. I am using the REST api. It's giving me an error "ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE". Here is the bad request:

```
`Host: demo.docusign.net
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"Kathleen.Harding-Lori@xxx.com","Password":"[omitted]","IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
X-Forwarded-For: 63.118.233.100, 165.225.34.90

{
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "name": "Kathy Keaton",
        "email": "KathyKeaton1@outlook.com",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "roleName": "##Buyer1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Kathy xxx",
        "email": "kathyxxx@hotmail.com",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "roleName": "##Seller1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Kathy Lloyd",
        "email": "KathyLloyd1@outlook.com",
        "routingOrder": "3",
        "roleName": "##RealEstateAgent"
      }
    ]
  },
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "1796af9e-06b2-463e-9b34-45dcee11653c"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Please Sign the enclosed docs at your earliest convenience"
}
400 BadRequest
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: d3964cc9-2470-408a-bcc8-0b160fa3a32e

{
  "errorCode": "ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE",
  "message": "The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line."
}`
```

There is no signing here, just viewing. There is a document, I have recipients and a subject line. Any idea where I could be going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using the **compositeTemplates** structure in the API request, the **recipients** need to be specified within an **inlineTemplates** object, as follows:

```
{  
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "1796af9e-06b2-463e-9b34-45dcee11653c"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
           "sequence" : 2,
           "recipients": {
               "signers":[
                  {
                    "name": "Kathy Keaton",
                    "email": "KathyKeaton1@outlook.com",
                    "routingOrder": "1",
                    "roleName": "##Buyer1",
                    "recipientId": "1"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Kathy xxx",
                    "email": "kathyxxx@hotmail.com",
                    "routingOrder": "2",
                    "roleName": "##Seller1",
                    "recipientId": "2"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Kathy Lloyd",
                    "email": "KathyLloyd1@outlook.com",
                    "routingOrder": "3",
                    "roleName": "##RealEstateAgent",
                    "recipientId": "3"
                  }            
               ]
           }
        }]    
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Please Sign the enclosed docs at your earliest convenience"
}
```

Also worth mentioning that if you're simply needing to specify recipient information for roles that are already defined by the (single) template, then a simpler way of doing so would be this:

```
{  
   "templateId": "1796af9e-06b2-463e-9b34-45dcee11653c"    
   "templateRoles":[
      {
        "name": "Kathy Keaton",
        "email": "KathyKeaton1@outlook.com",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "roleName": "##Buyer1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Kathy xxx",
        "email": "kathyxxx@hotmail.com",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "roleName": "##Seller1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Kathy Lloyd",
        "email": "KathyLloyd1@outlook.com",
        "routingOrder": "3",
        "roleName": "##RealEstateAgent"
      }            
   ], 
   "status": "sent",
   "emailSubject": "Please Sign the enclosed docs at your earliest convenience"
}
```

*Note:* Both of the above Request bodies should give you the same result. The **compositeTemplates** structure (as shown in the first Request) enables you to do things like create an Envelope that uses multiple templates, etc. -- but if you're simply creating an envelope from a single template, then the second Request shows a simpler way of doing that (i.e., without using the **compositeTemplates** structure).

Comment: Thank you so much Kim for all the help. One small issue with the composite template answer - you have to set the recipientId for the signers. The logging told me that. I am so happy you answered my question. These nuances of templateRoles and Signers was a big confusing, but it makes sense now.

Comment: I have one last question: I have a composite template in one envelope, 2 server templates, 2 signers, signer A and signer B. What I want is for signer A to see the first doc, sign it, and the first doc then goes to signer B and after B signs, A gets the second doc. But what I'm seeing is that signer A gets both docs at the same time. How to I remedy this?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include "recipientId" in the first example. Re your other question -- it sounds like you may want to add signer A twice in the routing order (first as recipient #1 and again as recipient #3) -- you'd need to set the "allowRecipientRecursion" property to "true" for the envelope to make this work.  Then, you can use the "Document Visibility" feature to specify which docs are visible to which recipients -- more info here: https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/cdse-user-guide/Content/advanced-sending/using-document-visibility.htm

Comment: You are super helpful to me. I didn't know about the "allowRecipientRecursion" property. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad that I could help!